# UIButton Strange Issue (wont release on releasing tap)

Tags: xamarin.ios, uibutton

I have a problem with UIButton and it is bizarre because I do not have it on similar occasions  in new projects. My problem:

I have four UIButton(s), when you hold your finger on one of them them, then when you tap on another button, even if you release your finger from the second button, until you release all the fingers from the screen, the buttons will not release. I guess that it is related to TouchEvents and TouchGestures like swipe and I am using all of them in my application.

Sincerely yours,

Peyman Mortazavi

Comment: My guess was right! buttons were children of a panel which I've override the touch functions to receive touch events.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself found the issue.

You need to make a separate panel inside of the main panel (let's say Root) and then put your buttons or any other UI there.

Regards,
Peyman Mortazavi